# Time Complexity with outer for loop and inner if loop

Tags: python, time-complexity

here tmp is a list

```
res=[]

for e in tmp:
    if not(e in res): 
        res.append(e)
```

For this code what will be the time complexity and why?

Comment: What do you think will be the time complexity? And why? How can you check it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is really a computer science or math question, not a programming question.

Comment: The time complexity is going to have a big O of N* N however this could also be N * log(n) depending on the structure of the "res" array.

Comment: We can check this by verifying the number of loops that are being computed, We know N since we loop through every value in the array tmp. then the additional complexity due the number of elements in res.

Comment: since there res is empty at the start, is there any way that the time complexity will be linear?

Comment: An `if` statement is not a loop, so the title is somewhat misleading.

Comment: @Blckknght `not in` will iterate through every element, given the `res` is a list, so technically, it is a loop under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for e in res:
```

this loop is computed len(res) times (lets call it n)

```
if not(e in res):
```

the search (since res is not sorted) is computed also, in worst case scenario, n times, since res can have max n elements

```
res.append(e)
```

and append() method is done with O(1) complexity,

So complexity of this function is O(n^2)

If don't have to maintain order you can make it faster with:

```
res = list(set(tmp))
```

And if you have to:

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet
res = list(OrderedSet(tmp))
```